# Chained comparison number range in Python

Tags: python, comparison, chained

I have the following function:

```
def InRange(number):
    return 5 <= number >= 1
```

I want this to say false if the number is not within the range of 1 to 5 using a chain comparison, but cannot seem to get this right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want it like this:

```
def InRange(number):
    return 1 <= number <= 5
```

Note that you could also do:

```
def InRange(number):
    return 0 < number < 6
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
1 <= number <= 5
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y` and `y <= z`, except that `y` is
>   evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when
>   `x < y` is found to be false).

Your (incorrect)expression is actually equivalent to:

```
number >=5 and number >= 1
```

So, it is going to be `True` for any number between 1 to infinity:

Comment: I think you mean it is going to be `True` for any number from **5** to infinity...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do (it seemed appropriate based on the function's name):

```
def InRange(number):
    return number in range(1, 6)
```

For large numbers you should use:

```
def InRange(number):
    return number in xrange(1, 10000000)
```

Comment: But don't use this for large ranges.

Comment: But note that something like `10**6 in xrange(1, 10000000)` takes around 40ms while `1 <= 10**6 <10000000` takes just 240ns. So, I'd always prefer mathematical comparison operators.

Comment: Much more improved membership tests in Py3.x though, `10**6 in range(1, 10000000)` took just `1.41us`.